# Android 2.2 webview search problem

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview in my activity. Now when I use `WebView.findAll()` method to search text in webview it is not highlighting the matching words.

It works fine in Android 1.6 but is not working in 2.2.

Comment: I have the same problem. Was any solution found?

Comment: No I didnt found any solution.

Comment: I need for solution for 4.0.3. Accepted answer works for 2.2, but not 3.2 or above. Answer of jianwu_chen works for 3.2, but not for 4.0.3.

Comment: Hi, anybody have solution for this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an issue in Android issue tracker about this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9018

I placed this code right after `WebView.findAll()`, and it made highlighting working:

```
try
{
    Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
    m.invoke(webView, true);
}
catch (Throwable ignored){}
```

Comment: This sounds like a nasty way to do it. But it does work! Thanks.

Comment: I am getting a problem here. My text is highlighted but the findAll() method returns 0. I am not able to understand why?? Any string i may take, it highlights them properly but the findAll() method always returns 0. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 8):

In android 4.0.3, seems the setFindIsUp is a private method. So above code won't work. As getMethod() method won't return the private methods. Following is a work-around to call the private method which works for 4.0.3:

```
try{
    //Can't use getMethod() as it's a private method
    for(Method m : WebView.class.getDeclaredMethods()){
        if(m.getName().equals("setFindIsUp")){
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(view, true);
            break;
        }
    }
}catch(Exception ignored){}
```

Comment: Although this code successfully find "setFindIsUp", but it seems not working for me. Highlighting is not appearing in 4.0.3, but it did with 2.2 (with this code).

Comment: Sorry, it works for 2.2 and 3.2, but not for 4.0.3! I need for solution for 4.0.3!