# Search for text in a WebView on Android 3.0 Honeycomb

Tags: android, webview, android-3.0-honeycomb, highlighting

I am developing an application on Android 3.0 Honeycomb.
Here I have WebView and I need to implement search functionality in this WebView i.e. The user can type any text in the search box (above in the Action bar) and that text should appear highlighted at all its occurrences in the WebView.

How can we achieve this? Do we need to use javascript here? If so, please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `WebView.findAll()` method to search text in webview

also check

[Android 2.2 webview search problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698457/android-2-2-webview-search-problem)

Comment: The provided method seems to work only for 2.2 it is not working for 3.0