# Android - WebView findall not working correctly on 4.0.3

Tags: android

I have a webview. Now when I use `WebView.findAll()` method to search text in the webview it is not highlighting the matching words.

It works fine in Android 2.2,3.2 but is not working in 4.0.3.

Do you have any ideas how I could implement this? I'd really appreciate your help.

```
webView.findAll(findString);  
try
{  
    Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);  
    m.setAccessible(true);
    m.invoke(webView, true);  
}
catch(Exception ignored){}
```

Comment: can you please post code ?

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10780676/2015318