# WebView findall doesen't work with android api 15

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to find and highlight text in a webView:

```
int API = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(API < 16) {
    wv.findAll(findBox.getText().toString());
} else {
    wv.findAllAsync(findBox.getText().toString());
}
```

However, it fails on api 15 only. It finds the word but doesen't highlight it. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem without a solution that I know of.  This occurs on the following:

```
Platform Version        API Level   VERSION_CODE
Android 4.0.3, 4.0.4    15          ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1
```

This problem is discussed: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698457/android-2-2-webview-search-problem) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910041/android-highlight-text-in-webview-above-android-version-4-0-3).